# Power BI create report in embedded mode throws 403

Tags: powerbi

When trying to create a Report in embedded mode (App owns data scenario), I followed [the official docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Create-Report-in-Embed-View#javascript-to-create-a-new-blank-report).
When calling
`report.saveAs(saveAsParameters);` method, I always receive an error response with status code 403.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to specify `tokenType` in the embedConfiguration:

```
var models = window['powerbi-client'].models;

var embedCreateConfiguration = {
    accessToken: 'eyJ0eXAiO...Qron7qYpY9MI',
    embedUrl: 'https://embedded.powerbi.com/ReportEmbed',
    datasetId: '5dac7a4a-4452-46b3-99f6-a25915e0fe55',
    tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
};
```

Remark: I can't contribute to Power Bi wiki page. Can someone pls check if it works and add this missing info.